# Javascript - regex - get string between /*color_1*/ and /*color_1_end*/

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get content between two style comment tags in html head, `/*color_1*/` and `/*color_1_end*/`. I tried:

```
var html = '/*color_1*/.welcome p, .intro p { color: #75735d;}/*color_1_end*/';
var testRE = html.match(/\/*color_1*\/(.*?)\/*color_1_end*\//i);
console.log(testRE);
```

But I guess I have the escaping wrong, or the regex wrong completely. How can I get the content between these tags with Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` character has special significance in regular expressions—it is a quantifier which means 'zero or more repetitions of the previous character, character class, or group'.

So if you want to match a literal `*` character, you need to escape it, like this:

```
var testRE = html.match(/\/\*color_1\*\/(.*?)\/\*color_1_end\*\//i);
```

To make this match across multiple lines, you'll have to use this little trick:

```
var testRE = html.match(/\/\*color_1\*\/([\s\S]*?)\/\*color_1_end\*\//i);
```

The character class `[\s\S]` means 'match any whitespace or non-whitespace character' (i.e. any character), though other metacharacters would also work (e.g. `[\d\D]`)